# PyOpenGL raises an exception after being frozen using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyopengl

I am making a game in PyOpenGL and want to freeze it using cx_Freeze. But it seems to me that importing PyOpenGL raises an exception in the PyOpenGL module.

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

When I run the frozen script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "/Users/noah/Desktop/DesktopNoah/cx_freeze/PhW.py", line 5, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL import error as _error
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/error.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenGL import platform, _configflags
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 29, in _load
    plugin = plugin_class()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I solve this issue and get PyOpenGL to work?

EDIT:
For people who don't have PyOpenGL, the below function shows how it is working:

```
import os, sys
from OpenGL.plugins import PlatformPlugin
def _load( ):
    """Load the os.name plugin for the platform functionality"""
    key = (os.environ.get( 'PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'), sys.platform,os.name)
    plugin  = PlatformPlugin.match( key )
    plugin_class = plugin.load()
    plugin.loaded = True
    # create instance of this platform implementation
    plugin = plugin_class()

    # install into the platform module's namespace now
    plugin.install(globals())
    return plugin

_load()
```

And also the platform plugin function:

```
class PlatformPlugin( Plugin ):
    """Platform-level plugin registration"""
    registry = []
    @classmethod
    def match( cls, key ):
        """Determine what platform module to load

        key -- (sys.platform,os.name) key to load 
        """
        for possible in key:
            # prefer sys.platform, *then* os.name
            for plugin in cls.registry:
                if plugin.name == possible:
                    return plugin
        raise KeyError( """No platform plugin registered for %s"""%(key,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `"OpenGL"` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe_options` in the `setup.py` script:

```py
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["OpenGL"]}

# ...

setup(  name = ...,  # complete!
        ...
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable(...)])
```

See the cx_Freeze [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script) for further details.

Comment: I did ```includes = ["OpenGL"]``` and ```options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }}```. Is this okay?

Comment: Thanks! I used ```includes``` instead of ```packages```. Now it worked.